# Outlook moves all days events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, appointments

I have a problem with my Outlook: When I make an all day appointment it will, over time, be moved one, two or more days.

It's allways moved to prior dates and it happens for events created on the Calendar as well asautomaticatly created events like birthday (created from the contact). In this last case, sometimes it will move only the apponitment but some others times it will also change the date on the Contact Form.

It's been happening a will and froma time I thought that the culprit was my Windows Mobile phone (and the sync utility) but since then I changed to Nokia phone and it keeps happening.

Any Ideas?

Rafael Bullrich

Buenos Aires, Argentina

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, check the time zones of all devices that access the email account. Older versions of Outlook were not very good at handling multiple time zones.